# Javascript setDate doesnt accept input

Tags: javascript, date

```
    <code>
    var d2 =  $('#interval').val();
    var new_date = new Date(get_start_date); 
    new_date.setDate(new_date.getDate() + d2);
    var dd = new_date.getDate();
    var mm = new_date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = new_date.getFullYear();
    var endDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    </code>
```

assuming d2 = 5

when im adding 5 dates to my current date, its not returning exact answer instead its adding months it becomes **2017-09-09**
but when i just do this **new_date.setDate(new_date.getDate() + 5)** it gives me the correct output.

Comment: try `var d2 =  Number($('#interval').val())`

Comment: are you sure you are getting right value of d2? It gives you string not number, just parse it as a number

Comment: @gurvinder372 that did the trick! Thank u very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse you d2 as an **integer**

`var d2 =  parseInt($('#interval').val(),10);`

Answer (score 0):

u can only use this arguments
new Date()
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

**get_start_date** is invailid ;)

> var new_date = new Date(**get_start_date**);